# No Internet on Ubuntu 18.04 - No Ping or curl to router / dns but can SSH

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet, connection

I changed my router last night and computers are fine and wireless fine etc. My development web server seemed fine I can access it any my websites and SSH etc however I noticed that I have no internet access.

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 instance with a static IP set however tested with DHCP and had the same situation with SSH etc but no internet access.

I'm guessing my config is in `/etc/netplan` and not `/etc/network/interfaces` for this version of ubuntu so have set below configs which seem to give me a working network connection (although i have set both the same as originally I used the latter and it didn't work):

> **/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.6/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.254
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

> **ifconfig:**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a60:6eff:fee5:e58b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:60:6e:e5:e5:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29347  bytes 3199867 (3.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4103  bytes 484556 (484.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

> **/sbin/route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

> **curl 192.168.1.254:**

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.254 port 80: No route to host
```

**Ping** fails to `8.8.8.8` and my gateway/router however works to other devices on the network. My new Draytek just doesn't seem to like my server. Nothing seems to show relating to my Server within syslog for the router so feel firewall isn't blocking anything there either. Firewall is also disabled on Ubuntu I believe:

```
ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Further investigations show from the router itself I can only ping a few machines not sure what this means but from the Ubuntu box i can ping different machines.

```
Ping out of Ubuntu 18.04
192.168.1.6 > 192.168.1.20 Ping OK
192.168.1.6 > 192.168.1.254 No Ping
192.168.1.6 > 192.168.1.1 Ping Ok
192.168.1.6 > 192.168.1.53 No Ping

Ping out of Router (Draytek 2960)
192.168.1.254 > 192.168.1.20 No Ping
192.168.1.254 > 192.168.1.6 No Ping
192.168.1.254 > 192.168.1.1 Ping OK
192.168.1.254 > 192.168.1.53 No Ping

Ping out of my Windows Machines
192.168.1.53 > 192.168.1.20 Ping OK
192.168.1.53 > 192.168.1.6 Ping OK
192.168.1.53 > 192.168.1.254 Ping OK
192.168.1.53 > 192.168.1.1 Ping OK
```

So Windows machine seems happy just some devices non windows ones don't seem to be playing ball with router. The 1.20 is a printer and 1.1 the main domain server here.

Any recommendations of what to try here as am out of ideas myself and none of the above makes much sense as to why different devices are PINGABLE from each machine and SSH and PING HTTP all seem to work / not work depending on source?